# Numpy union arrays in order

Tags: python, numpy

I've got three different numpy arrays

```
a = array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12])
b = array([ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13])
c = array([ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14])
```

How can I join them using numpy methods that

```
d = array[(0,1,2,3,4,...,12,13,14)]
```

I don't want to write a loop like

```
for i in range(len(a)):
 [...]
```

This is only an example in my project the arrays are not sorted and I want to keep their order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transpose and flatten the arrays:

```
d = numpy.array([a, b, c]).T.flatten()
```

An alternative way to combine the arrays is to use `numpy.vstack()`:

```
d = numpy.vstack((a, b, c)).T.flatten()
```

(I don't know which one is faster, by the way.)

**Edit**: In response to the [answer by Nicolas Barbey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830636/279627), here is how to make do with copying the data only once:

```
d = numpy.empty((len(a), 3), dtype=a.dtype)
d[:, 0], d[:, 1], d[:, 2] = a, b, c
d = d.ravel()
```

This code ensures that the data is layed out in a way that `ravel()`
does not need to make a copy, and indeed it is quite a bit faster than the original code on my machine:

```
In [1]: a = numpy.arange(0, 30000, 3)
In [2]: b = numpy.arange(1, 30000, 3)
In [3]: c = numpy.arange(2, 30000, 3)
In [4]: def f(a, b, c):
   ...:     d = numpy.empty((len(a), 3), dtype=a.dtype)
   ...:     d[:, 0], d[:, 1], d[:, 2] = a, b, c
   ...:     return d.ravel()
   ...: 
In [5]: def g(a, b, c):
   ...:     return numpy.vstack((a, b, c)).T.ravel()
   ...: 
In [6]: %timeit f(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.4 us per loop
In [7]: %timeit g(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 177 us per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
d = np.vstack((a, b, c)).T.ravel()
```

This saves one copy over .flatten() so it can be faster on large arrays.

EDIT: As stated by Sven Marnach this does not save a copy in this case.

vstack is faster than array for some reason :

```
In [1]: a = ones(1e4)

In [2]: b = ones(1e4)

In [3]: c = ones(1e4)

In [4]: %timeit np.vstack((a, b, c)).T.ravel()
1000 loops, best of 3: 265 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit np.vstack((a, b, c)).T.flatten()
1000 loops, best of 3: 268 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit np.array((a, b, c)).T.ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.24 ms per loop

In [7]: def test(a, b, c):
    d = numpy.empty((len(a), 3), dtype=a.dtype)
    d.T[:] = a, b, c
    d = d.ravel()
    return d

In [8]: %timeit test(a, b, c)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.06 ms per loop

In [9]: def test2(a, b, c):
            d = np.empty((len(a), 3), dtype=a.dtype)
            d[:, 0], d[:, 1], d[:, 2] = a, b, c
            d = d.ravel()
            return d

In [9]: %timeit test2(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.8 us per loop
```

Comment: The use of `ravel()` does not save a copy in this case, since the data isn't layed out in the correct order in memory.  There is no way of avoiding this copy after using `vstack()`.  The code in the current answers (mine and yours) does *two* copies in total.  This can be reduced to a single copy with a different trick – I'll add some code to my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why assigning to `d.T[:]` is that slow.  Using `d[:, 0], d[:, 1], d[:, 2]` as assignment target instead speed the code up by a factor of 40 on my machine – I updated my answer again. :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Unfortunately, your new implementation is not any faster than the first vstack + flatten / ravel.

Comment: Indeed, your last version rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

try it...

```
reduce (numpy.union1d, (a, b, c))
```